# Launch GUI app on iOS 5 through the command line (jailbreak)

Tags: ios, command-line, jailbreak, launch

I believe you used to be able to launch GUI apps on jailbroken iOS devices via the command line (over SSH) by executing a command like this:

```
launch com.apple.Calculator
```

but that is not working on my iOS 5 device (`launch not found`).

I also tried:

```
launchctl start com.apple.Calculator
```

but that also gives me an error (`no such process`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those `launch`/`launchctl` commands didn't work for me either. What did work was to install the command-line utilty `open` from Cydia and just execute

```
open com.apple.calculator
```

Notice the lowercase c in `calculator,` that was the bundle identifier for my calculator app.

Here's the developer's website for Cydia stuff:

http://kramerapps.com/cydia/

This links to the repo site:

http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=openData

Update: For iOS 6.x, this current version of `open` doesn't seem to work. See @Nate's answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202441/ios-6-x-open-command-line-on-jailbreak) linked below in the comments.

Update 2: The `open` package in Cydia has been updated and now works with iOS 6.

Update 3: Here is the source for the package: https://github.com/conradev/Open.
If you look at the `open.m` file, you can see that the function `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier` from the `SpringBoardServices` private framework is what actually opens the app.

Comment: I love you. I can now get 10 seconds of my life back for every time I compile - i.e. a hundred times per day :)

Comment: don't love me, love the dude who created `open` ;)

Comment: Can you share the package name?

Comment: It should be just `open`, but I've added links above as well.

Comment: can't open application on IOS6. Will cause springboard crash and enter safe mode.

Comment: @Vanguarder: yeah, the package doesn't seem to be compatible with iOS 6 and no update as of yet.

Comment: @Vanguarder, see my answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15202441/119114), which gives you a workaround by building your own version of `open`.

Comment: FYI, to install open (now updated for iOS 7) use `apt-get install com.conradkramer.open`