# Open app with "open"-command in locked screen (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, ssh, command, screen, locked

is there a possibility to open an app via the open command while i am in locked screen?

im getting this error: Couldn't open application: "app-name". Reason: 3, device locked

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Which open command you are talking about?

Comment: it is an cydia package which gives you the opportunity to open any app with the "open"-comman via ssh.. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759042/launch-gui-app-on-ios-5-through-the-command-line-jailbreak/11383664#11383664)

Comment: my problem is that i can't execute the command while my ipod/iphone is in locked screen, it shows me the error message i posted above.. does exist a workaround for that?

Answer (score 4):

Does the device have to be locked when you run the app? I use Activator from Cydia to wake and unlock the device via SSH and then launch with Open. This is for iPad mini but you can change the values for stouch depending on your device.

```
activator send libactivator.system.homebutton && sleep 1 && stouch swipe 200 300 700 300 0.2 1
```

Comment: What package is `stouch` part of? Doesn't seem to be installed on my device, but the activator part works awesomely

Comment: Same question here.. how to get stouch?